# How can I change the location of the bin-release folder in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

When I right click on the bin-release folder and click properties, then click Resource, the Location is: C:\Users\anotheruser\Desktop\TEST CFA. How do I change this to actually be the bin-release folder that I created in my application?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the 'Project' > build path > (source tab) change the default output folder.

Comment: When I right click on the Project I don't get the option 'Build path'

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was delete the current bin-release folder and create a new one. Then it all seemed to work.